# Python package installed but cannot be used, pip search throws tracebacks

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I've installed a package to use instead of SimpleHTTPServer, which wasn't working for some reason:

```
# python3 -m pip install http-here
Requirement already satisfied: http-here in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: click in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from http-here)
```

But when trying to use it, I've got this error:

```
  # python3 -m http-here
/usr/bin/python3: No module named http-here
```

Pip search among other output shows Traceback:

```
# python3 -m pip search http-here
http-here (0.0.2)        - Simple Python HTTP server short for SimpleHTTPServer.
  INSTALLED: 0.0.2 (latest)

--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 983, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ub294' in position 78: ordinal not in range(128)
Call stack:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
    sys.exit(pip.main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 233, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 52, in run
    print_results(hits, terminal_width=terminal_width)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 118, in print_results
    logger.info(line)
Message: 'hacked-http (0.0.1)                                          - Hacked Urllib2 \ub294 warning.or.kr \uac19\uc740 \ubc29\uc5b4\ubcbd\uc744 \ub6ab\ub294\ub370 \ubaa9\uc801\uc774 \uc788\uc2b5\ub2c8\ub2e4.'
```

**Hacked Urllib2** is of concern to me.

My Python and pip version:

```
# python3 -V
Python 3.5.3
# python3 -m pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

Also, **python3-pip** seams to be installed, but also doesn't work when invoked through CLI:

```
# apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.

# python3-pip search whatever
-bash: python3-pip: command not found

# which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

My locale output stubbornly shows some empty fields, could this be the reason for traceback and should I write it in /etc/environment ?

```
# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
...
LC_ALL=
```

Am I hitting some python bug, which I need to report, or how to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Adding

`export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"`

to `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` just to be sure this never happens again, got rid of the Traceback.

About **Hacked Urllib2** `pip search` shows available packages, not installed, to see installed I've used `pip list` and this trash wasn't there which is good.

About

```
# python3 -m http-here
/usr/bin/python3: No module named http-here
```

It should be called as `pip3`

And

```
python3 -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Should be used instead of SimpleHTTPServer which is for python2